# Floated items in "gallery" layout break to next line at random browser widths

Tags: html, css, css-float, responsive-design

I have a group of six percentage-width boxes that are supposed to display three per line. They are floated left and all are the same size, but at seemingly random browser widths, the fourth item floats all the way to the right and the last two items are pushed down to a third line. The markup for each is the same and the images are all sized the same, so I'm not sure what could be causing this. The page exists [here](http://staging.lifestylerevolutionstx.com). When you adjust the browser width you will see what I mean.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="promoItem"> 
                <img src="img/promo/groupFitness.jpg">
                <div class="colorBG"></div>
                <div class="promoLabel">Group Fitness Classes</div>
            </div>

            <div class="promoItem"> 
                <img src="img/promo/mealPlans.jpg">
                <div class="colorBG"></div>
                <div class="promoLabel">Custom Meal Plans</div>
            </div>

            <div class="promoItem"> 
                <img src="img/promo/personalTraining.jpg" />
                <div class="colorBG"></div>
                <div class="promoLabel">Personalized Fitness Plans</div>
            </div>

            <div class="promoItem"> 
                <img src="img/promo/fitnessVideos.jpg">
                <div class="colorBG"></div>
                <div class="promoLabel">Fitness Videos</div>
            </div>

            <div class="promoItem"> 
                <img src="img/promo/healthyRecipes.jpg">
                <div class="colorBG"></div>
                <div class="promoLabel">Healthy Recipes</div>
            </div>

            <div class="promoItem"> 
                <img src="img/promo/emailSignup.png" />
                <div class="colorBG"></div>
                <div class="promoLabel">Join our mailing list</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div.promoItem { 
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 29.333333%;
  margin: 0 2% 20px 2%;
}

div.promoItem img { 
  z-index: 1; 
  max-width: 100%;
}
div.promoItem div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;

}
div.promoItem div.colorBG {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #FFD700;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=75);
  opacity: 0.75;
}

div.promoItem:hover div.promoLabel {
  background-color: #FFD700;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
} 

div.promoItem div.promoLabel {
  z-index: 3;
  color: #0D42C0;
}
```

Comment: Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JonBMN/Yt72A/) so that people can see what your doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I can't say this is the only solution, but here's how I feel you could fix this problem:

Looking at the site, I believe the issue lies with the dimensions of the images being used for those `<div class="promoItem">` elements. The variation between heights of your assets (264px-265px) seems to be causing the line breaks. You can fix this in a couple of ways:

1. Standardize the heights of the assets you use in those instances. Since you don't have many images there, this shouldn't be a very lengthy task - but if they change, you'll have to remember the correct height to make the new assets with. Or, you can...
2. ...Change your CSS to be a bit more flexible. These changes seem to work for me:

   ```
   div.promoItem {
       position: relative;
       display: inline-block;
       width: 29%;
       margin: 0 2% 20px 2%;
   }
   ```

   (The possible off-center by 1-ish px shouldn't be noticeable, but if it poses a problem, add `text-align: center` to the parent `<div>`)

(Edit) I also noticed the design is responsive. As such, for the smaller screen size (where the elements are 2 per row), you'll need to change `width:46%` to about `width:45.5%`. Again, this can be centered if needed by the suggestion mentioned above.

Again, these are just a couple ways that can address the perceived problem, there are probably plenty of others out there. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Serlite! That took care of the problem.

Comment: Glad I could help! Oh and, uhm...if you thought my answer was good, could you also give it an upvote?

(Edit) Oops! I forgot you need 15 Rep to upvote. Neeeever mind...XD

Comment: Yes indeed, otherwise I absolutely would have!